# how to load more than one xml bean files in spring IOC

Tags: spring-ioc

how to load more than one bean xml configuration file in springIOC container(either in BeanFactory or in AppilcationContext).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple config files when constructing your application context:

```
ApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"context1.xml",
          "context2.xml","context3.xml"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web application and if you are using WebApplicationContext then in your web.xml you can specify xml files under  tag like below

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext1.xml


     </param-value>
</context-param>
```